# How do i know if a specific date is a month, or a week to an parent date?

Tags: ios, swift, calendar, nsdate

Lets say i have a program that reminds users of their appointments , from the current date until the date of the appointment, i want to find out if a particular date is a week to the appointment or a month to the appointment .

```
var startDate = startDate
let calendar = Calendar.current

let fmt = DateFormatter()
fmt.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"

while startDate <= endDate {

    var  newDate = calendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: startDate)!


    if newDate is a month to endDate {

        //schedule reminder
    }

    if newDate is a week to endDate{

        //schedule reminder
    }
```

how can i check if the current date is a week/month to the appointment ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use any date comparison, you can simply generate the notification dates using `Calendar.date(byAdding:value:to:)` and just passing the correct components. To set the date 1 week/month before `endDate`, pass `-1` to value.

```
let oneWeekBeforeAppointment = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .weekOfYear, value: -1, to: endDate)!
let oneMonthBeforeAppointment = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .month, value: -1, to: endDate)!
```

Comment: Why do i need to pass a `-1`  what if i pass `1` do you have any idea of the  implications ?

Comment: @BigFire a negative value means moving the date to the past, while a positive one moving it to the future. So if you changed `-1` to `1`, that would mean the date would be 1 week/month __after__ the previous date, not __before__ it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to calculate the duration in days

```
func DateFormat() -> DateFormatter {
  let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
  dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"
  dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "GMT")
  return dateFormatter
}

var appointementDate: Date?
var today = Date()

appointementDate = DateFormat().date(from: "22/02/2020")
today = DateFormat().date(from: DateFormat().string(from: today))!

let timeInterval = Int(exactly: (today.timeIntervalSince(appointementDate!))) ?? 0
print("\(timeInterval/86400) days left")
```